# function to pick the largest number

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to make a function that picks up the largest number in an array, but I can't seem to get it to go past the first number.

```
function largestNumber(numbers) {
  var constant = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if(numbers[i] > constant) {
          constant = numbers[i];
      }
      return constant;        
    }
}
var numbers = [3, 4, 2, 6, 45, 775, 83, 5, 7];

largestNumber(numbers);
```

Comment: Because you return on first iteration...

Comment: ^ What Andrew said, take it out of your for loop.

Comment: FYI: `Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);` does exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: Such bugs can be found easily by walking through your code with a debugger. Did you try that?

Comment: In general, the maximum of zero numbers is considered to be negative infinity. That's the way `Math.max` works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function largestNumber(numbers) {
    var constant = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > constant) {
            constant = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return constant;    // after iterating the entire array!
}
var numbers = [3, 4, 2, 6, 45, 775, 83, 5, 7];
console.log(largestNumber(numbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max//) with spread operator

```js
 function largestNumber(arr) {
   return Math.max(...arr);
 }
    
var numbers=[3,4,2,6,45,775,83,5,7];
largestNumber(numbers);

console.log(largestNumber(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was, you were returning early.

```js
function largestNumber(numbers) {
  // return null by default
  var result = null;

  if (numbers.length) {
    // if there is a value in the array, return it by default
    result = numbers[0];
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if (numbers[i] > result) {
        result = numbers[i];
      }
    } // <= you were returning too early
  }
  return result;
}

var numbers = [3, 4, 2, 6, 45, 775, 83, 5, 7];
largestNumber(numbers);
```

Comment: In general this would be considered a typo suitable for voting to close with that as a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generator which returns the largest number seen so far:

```
function *max(array) {
  let result = -Infinity;
  for (let v of array) yield result = v > result ? v : result;
}
```

You can find the maximum of an array by taking the last element:

```
function last(array) { return array[array.length - 1]; }

const numbers = [3, 4, 2, 6, 45, 775, 83, 5, 7];

console.log(last([...max(numbers)]));
```

The `[...]` is needed to convert the stream of results from the generator into an array; `Array.from` would also work.